# Get all classes of a package

Tags: scala, reflection

How can I get a list of all classes in a given package?
I tried this:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => cm}  
val classes = cm.staticPackage("scala.collection.mutable").typeSignature.declarations
```

But it seems to give me an empty list.

Comment: I've not used it, but this library seems to provide the kind of introspection you're looking for: https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, this is not possible, because the runtime reflection part of the Scala reflection API is based on classloaders, and they don't provide the functionality of enumerating contents of packages.